# How can this destroy action be tested with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In my Rails app, if a `user` wants to delete his own account he will first have to enter his password in my `terminate` view:

```
<%= form_for @user, :method => :delete do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This is my `UsersController`:

```
def terminate
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @title = "Terminate your account"
end

def destroy
  if @user.authenticate(params[:user][:password])
    @user.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your account was terminated."
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = "Wrong password."
    render :terminate
  end
end
```

The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to test this with RSpec.

What I have is this:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do

  before :each do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  context "success" do

    it "deletes the user" do
      expect{ 
        delete :destroy, :id => @user, :password => "password"
      }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

  end

end
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate:
Missing template users/destroy, application/destroy with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
* "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x007fa7f51310d8>"
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm missing here or suggest a better way to test this action?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: the error you get is very weird. BTW, you dont send the right params

Comment: Have you got the relevant view templates in place?

Comment: @NeilBillingham with this implementation, OP doesn't need `destroy` template, but the lack of this template is what RSpec complains for.

Comment: Does changing the request line in tests to this delete :destroy, :id => @user.id, :password => "password" makes a difference?

Comment: @apneadiving: You are probably right. I am always trying to keep my questions as short as possible and sometimes I get carried away. Sorry about that.

Comment: @NeilBillingham: Yes, I have them all.

Comment: @MarekLipka: You are right. I created an empty file `destroy.html.erb` and that eliminated the error. Even after removing that file again, the error is still gone.

Comment: @Tumas: Nope, that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK, this is my solution:

```
describe 'DELETE #destroy' do

  context "success" do

    it "deletes the user" do
      expect{ 
        delete :destroy, :id => @user, :user => {:password => @user.password}
     }.to change(User, :count).by(-1)
    end

  end

end
```

The `before :each` call I had before was useless (this is not an integration test after all). The password has to be passed in like this: `:user => {:password => @user.password}` which I didn't know until reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748772/passing-form-params-in-rspec).

Comment: Why I'm getting ArgumentError:
       unknown keywords: id, user

Comment: in Rails 6 im getting unknown keyword id ?